# Unable to update the icon images dynamically after refresh of the data for every x seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am currently updating the markers dynamically for every x seconds here the data updating and placing the markers but here the issue is when ever the data is update according to the icon images are not updating here i place

```
0== red
1== green
2== orange 

here this.markerIcon = this.mapData[i].OrderState;  this is my icon color status
```

below is my code which is getting the dynamic data

```
if(this.mapData!=null && this.mapData.length>0){

          for (var i = 0; i < this.mapData.length;i++){
            this.latlng = {lat: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].latitude), lng: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].longitude)};

            this.markerName = this.mapData[i].Name; 

            this.markerIcon = this.mapData[i].OrderState;

            if (this.markerStore.hasOwnProperty(this.mapData[i].DriverId)) {

              if (this.markerIcon === "0") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.red;

              } else if (this.markerIcon === "1") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.green;

              } else if ( this.markerIcon === "2") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.orange;
              } else if (this.markerIcon === "3") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.building;
              }
              this.markerStore[this.mapData[i].DriverId].setPosition(this.latlng);
            } else {
              if (this.markerIcon === "0") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.red;

              } else if (this.markerIcon === "1") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.green;

              } else if ( this.markerIcon === "2") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.orange;
              } else if (this.markerIcon === "3") {
                this.iconDisplay = this.building;
              }

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: this.latlng,
                map:this.mapObject,
                icon:this.iconDisplay
              });
              this.markerStore[this.mapData[i].DriverId] = marker;
            }
          }
        }

      }

    });
```

and when i press reload page then the icon color change  is happening i don't know what's wrong

Json data:

```
{
"Data": [
{
"DriverId": "138",
"Name": "A",
"OrderState": "1",
"latitude": "35.20714666666667",
"longitude": "55.32000000001"
},
{
"DriverId": "4",
"Name": "T",
"OrderState": "2",
"latitude": "35.7828333333337",
"longitude": "58.764833333334"
},
{
"DriverId": "7",
"Name": "AL",
"OrderState": "2",
"latitude": "35.677546666666665",
"longitude": "85.27641833333334"
},
{
"DriverId": "111",
"Name": "Waseem.",
"OrderState": "0",
"latitude": "25.199691666666663",
"longitude": "55.249858333333336"
},
{
"DriverId": "5",
"Name": "D",
"OrderState": "0",
"latitude": "35.19730666666667",
"longitude": "65.56744999999999"
},
{
"DriverId": "137",
"Name": "G",
"OrderState": "1",
"latitude": "36.240411666666667",
"longitude": "65.27219333333334"
}
],
"ErrorCode": "201 - Success",
"Message": "Success",
"Status": true
}
```

here based on order state value im changin the marker image 0 == red and 1 == green and 2 == orange every 10 seconds the data will be updated and 0 may become 1 or 2 also

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm displaying the dynamic data in the form of marker and for every 10 sec Im getting live data from the server and here what happened is I able to display data and customarkers also here custom marker based on values from the backend it chnages now what happened is even though the value from the backend is correct but the icon image is not updating and after I press reload in browser then it is updating the image

Comment: @Madpop use console log or developer tools to watch the variable values in your if else logic

Comment: @Deep3015 at the first init the data of the marker is inserting correctly after refresh / Update intervals it is not updating

Comment: Ok I will recreate sample, add sample data to work

Comment: @Deep3015  json data added

Comment: @Deep3015 any luck

Comment: @Madpop check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-google-maps-dmxclh?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: This question is lacking more information (A Minimal, Complete, and Verificable example). Without that it is very difficult to troubleshoot the problem that you are presenting. Some reasons for this to fail are: You are update this.iconDisplay, but, what is this in the context? It could be that you are modifiying the same iconDisplay all the time. 
It could also be that you are not executing your code everytime you receive an update, it could be that google maps is not getting refresh after your changes. Please provide a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the marker exists instead of replacing element in the array remove the old marker and add a new one.

```
if (this.mapData[i].DriverId in this.markerStore) {
     this.markerStore[this.mapData[i].DriverId].setMap(null);
}
// create here the new one as you did before
```